# How to find the min and max values from a list in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have tried the below code snippet, but it throws an error regarding typecasting because the list has a combination of integer and double values. But `list.reduce(min)` returns onlyan integer value. Could you please provide a solution for this?

**Note --** However I have only the `List` of `dynamic` from the user.

```dart
final List<dynamic> y = [12, 12, 23.5, 2, 19, 1, 23, 16, 29.7, 32, 45, 68, 23, 21];
List<num> yValues = y;
num yMin = yValues.reduce(min);
num yMax = yValues.reduce(max);
```

Answer (score 6):

You are writing that the List are of the type `List<dynamic>`. Since `min` and `max` only works on `num` type we need to `cast` each element of the list to `num` like this:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final List<dynamic> y = <dynamic>[12, 12, 23.5, 2, 19, 1, 23, 16, 29.7, 32, 45, 68, 23, 21];
  final yMin = y.cast<num>().reduce(min);
  final yMax = y.cast<num>().reduce(max);
  print(yMin); // 1
  print(yMax); // 68
}
```

Comment: I mean if he really wants to add the types, then might as well make the list List<num> than List<dynamic>

Comment: I guess he got the list from JSON parsing or some other kind of source. Again, the question is about he already got this list which are `List<dynamic>`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do not recommend using 3rd party packages, but those ones that are generic and from trusted developer are good. One of the is [quiver](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver):

```dart
...
import 'package:quiver/iterables.dart' as quiver;
...

final y = [12, 12, 23.5, 2, 19, 1, 23, 16, 29.7, 32, 45, 68, 23, 21];
num yMin = quiver.min(y);
num yMax = quiver.max(y);
```

Comment: How is this package better than `dart:math` in this case ?

Comment: Not a package but rather its min function: it is semantically finds min/max element of collection. While using reduce and passing math's min/max is basically duplication of reduce. So basically it encapsulates function of finding min/max element, while with reduce you are implementing logic yourself

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final y = [12, 12, 23.5, 2, 19, 1, 23, 16, 29.7, 32, 45, 68, 23, 21, 69.1];
  var yMin = y.reduce(min);
  var yMax = y.reduce(max);
}
```

Comment: what is min and max?

Comment: @KarunShrestha Two methods found in the `dart:math` package which the example also show being imported: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-math/min.html and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-math/max.html